# mongodb raises duplicate key error while inserting data

Tags: mongodb

while creating a Node API i have set employeeId as unique. here is the schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const devSchema =new  mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name :{
            type : String,
            required : [true, "please enter name"]
        },
        employeeId : {
            type : Number,
            required : [true, "please enter id"],
            unique : true
        },
        salary : {
            type : Number,
            required : [true,"enter salary"]
        },
        employmentDate : {
            type : Date
        }
    }
)

module.exports = mongoose.model('dev',devSchema)
```

after entering 1 data with employeeId=1 when i try to insert another record with employeeid=2 it is giving me error although employeeId is unique.here is the error
function Error() { [native code] }MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: SDE.devs index: id_1 dup key:
{ id: null }

I am trying to insert data with unique employeeId

Comment: It looks like the error is related to an index on an `id` property, not `employeeId`. I would guess you created an index previously, removed it from your schema, forgot to drop the index in the database and now you have 1 document still in there with an `id: null` so now when you try to create a new document mongoose is giving that new document an `id: null` which in turn fails the unique constraint. Use mongosh or compass to query your data to find out and see [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndexes/#db.collection.dropindexes--) to dop it.

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot and resolve the issue, you can follow below steps:

1. **Existing Data**: Verify that there are no existing records with the same `employeeId` in your MongoDB collection.
2. **Error Handling**: In case of a duplicate key error, indicate to the user that a record with the provided `employeeId` already exists.
3. **Debugging**: Review your code to confirm there's no inadvertent attempt to insert duplicate `employeeId` values.

Example code:

```js
try {
    // Insert data into MongoDB collection using mongoose
} catch (error) {
    if (error.code === 11000 || error.code === 11001) {
        // Throw error that a record with the same employeeId already exists
        res.status(400).json({ error: 'A record with the provided EmployeeId already exists' });
    } else {
        // Handle other MongoDB errors
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    }
}
```

Following these steps should help resolve the issue of duplicate key errors in your project.